# Multiple validator for Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I want to create multiple validator for forms which will be used to create or edit some objects.
I have `User` model with such method:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ];
    }
```

I have default resource `UserController`:

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        request()->validate($user->rules()); //this is nice according to mvc pattern (I hope it is)
        User::create([ 
            ...
        ]);
    }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
        User::find($id)->update($request->all());
        ...
    }
```

`update()` method does not have `User` instance as parameter unlike `store()`. But I don't want to have any excessive code. Should I make `rules()` static and use `User::rules()`? I know that it is pretty hard to test static methods, but I actually don't know any pros and cons for such way. Any good sollutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using FormRequests to keep your code separated.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation

They allow you to validate your requests without doing so in the controller methods as well as augment the validation data before it reaches the validator.

Another big benefit is the `authorize()` method, where you can fine tune even further who can access a route method and how.

You can define a BaseFormRequest class with a common set of rules that you can inherit from.

If validation fails, it will automatically flash the errors to the session or if the request is ajax, return a JSON response.

Comment: Thanks, this one is nice. But anyway I don't want to create two `FormRequest` for both `store()` and `update()`. Is it possible to assign `FormRequest` to specific route?

Comment: Yes, you type hint the method with the appropriate FormRequest. For example, `update(UpdateFormRequest $request)` and `store(StoreFormRequest $request)`

Comment: So anyway I need two similar `rules()` array, but one of them (which is for `update()`) would have `unique` parameter. I just worry about this duplicated code

Comment: That's where a BaseFormRequest comes in. FormRequests inheriting from the base could do `public function rules () { return array_merge(parent::rules(), [... custom rules...]); }`. I take a similar approach in several projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you used same validation for insert and update, you will get problem when update, because the rule has:

```
enter code here`'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users'
```

it mean the update will always fail on 'unique:users' validation because the email has recorded on database.

I think static function is not bad if you prefer. there's many style in programming and you can choose your own style. the final is same, *make it work*.

Based on your condition, I prefer to make it static variable rather than need to calling a function, because the rules is just an array of string. But you need to use PHP7.

```
class User {
    static $RULES =  [
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            ];
}
```

then when need rules to update, I will make custom unique validation that can accept except argument, such as:

```
$rules = User::$RULES; //Clone
$rules[email] .= " id!={$user->id}" // Append with space
// Email rule will like this
// required|string|email|max:255|unique:users id!=23
```

Then I need to modify the unique validation to support that argument. This example to handle it:

```
function unique($str_to_validate, $rule)
{
    if( strpos($rule, ' ') !== false )
    {
        //Has except object notation
        list($rule, $condition) = explode(' ', $rule, 2);
        //Add where condition on DB query
        $this->db->where($condition);
    }

    // Your default validation here
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You answer inspired me to take a look on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators) about `unique` and I found this way to ignore `Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),`

Comment: Yes, laravel is a good framework, but I'm not familiar with it so I don't know if you use laravel (I'm not read the question tag)